# @ModelAttribute method to prevent handler method to in invoked

Tags: spring-mvc, modelattribute

I'm using `@ModelAttribute` annotation on a method to populate the model in my controller and perform some logic. Is there a way for the `@ModelAttribute` annotated method to prevent continuing to the handler of the invoked method, that is scheduled to fire right after it?

Comment: pleass share code

Answer (score 0):

Well, the @ModelAttribute should't prevent to handle the service or controller once we are using the annotation, can you please post the code and more details where you are having the issue?